# Iterate over N nested list and dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following structure of JSON/Dict.

```
[
{
    "childrens": [
        {
            "childrens": [
                {
                    "name": "somenam1"
                }
            ],
            "name": "B999"
        }
    ],
    "name": "11111"
},
{
    "childrens": [
        {
            "childrens": [
                {
                    "name": "somename2"
                },
                {
                    "name": "somename3"
                }
            ],
            "name": "B5555"
        },
        {
            "childrens": [
                {
                    "name": "somename4"
                }
            ],
            "name": "B2222"
        }
    ],
    "name": "2222"
}
```

]

I want to iterate over all dictionaries and list inside root list and create single string for each dictionary inside root list.

Output will look like this (two lines):

```
1111|B999|somename1

2222|B5555|somename2|somename3|B2222|somename4
```

Also this is just an example i can have N nested childrens.

Comment: could you add more information about things that you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a good candidate for recursion:

```
def flatten(child):
    if not child:
        return child
    return [child['name']] + [name for c in child.get('childrens', []) for name in flatten(c)]

In []:
for child in data:
    print('|'.join(flatten(child)))

Out[]:
11111|B999|somenam1
2222|B5555|somename2|somename3|B2222|somename4
```

Sure you can just pass add a `level` arg and return that:

```
def flatten(child, level=0):
    if not child:
        return child
    return [level] + [l for c in child.get('childrens', []) for l in flatten(c, level+1)]

In []:
for child in data:
    print('|'.join(str(level) for level in flatten(child)))

Out[]:
0|1|2
0|1|2|2|1|2
```

Comment: Is there any way to figure out on which level is found each element. If we take same example, output will be:
0|1|2 
 next line 
0|1|2|2|1|2
?

Comment: Sure, just add a `level` argument, and increment it on the recursion. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution by recursion

```
data_json = '[{"childrens":[{"childrens":[{"name":"somenam1"}],"name":"B999"}],"name":"11111"},{"childrens":[{"childrens":[{"name":"somename2"},{"name":"somename3"}],"name":"B5555"},{"childrens":[{"name":"somename4"}],"name":"B2222"}],"name":"2222"}]'

data = json.loads(data_json)

def get_names(data_dict):
  if ("childrens" in data_dict):
    ret_dict = "|".join(map(get_names, data_dict["childrens"]))
    return data_dict["name"] + "|" + ret_dict
  else:
    return data_dict["name"]

def get_all_name(data):
  for i in data:
    print(get_names(i))

get_all_name(data)
```